# as.Date() is sensitive to the order of values in the input vector

Tags: r

I noticed that if the *first* element of the input vector to `as.Date()` can't be converted, it makes *all* elements `NA`. If the first element is OK, than all others are saved:

```
input1 <- c('2001-02-03','-', '-', '2002-03-04')
input2 <- c('-','2001-02-03', '2002-03-04')

as.Date(input1)
# "2001-02-03" NA           NA           "2002-03-04"

as.Date(input2)
# Error in charToDate(x) : 
#  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.Date(input2, optional=TRUE)
# NA NA NA
```

`?base::as.Date` help doesn't say anything about the order of elements. Can it be considered a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `as.Date`, specify the `format` as according to `?as.Date`

> format - character string. If not specified, it will try **tryFormats** one by one on the **first non-NA element**, and give an **error if none works**. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime() whose help page describes available conversion specifications.

```
 as.Date(input2, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
[1] NA           "2001-02-03" "2002-03-04"
```

Based on the error showed, it is calling the `as.Date.character`

```
function (x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"), 
    optional = FALSE, ...) 
{
    charToDate <- function(x) {
        is.na(x) <- !nzchar(x)
        xx <- x[1L]
        if (is.na(xx)) {
            j <- 1L
            while (is.na(xx) && (j <- j + 1L) <= length(x)) xx <- x[j]
            if (is.na(xx)) 
                f <- "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
        if (is.na(xx)) 
            strptime(x, f)
        else {
            for (ff in tryFormats) if (!is.na(strptime(xx, ff, 
                tz = "GMT"))) 
                return(strptime(x, ff))
            if (optional) 
                as.Date.character(rep.int(NA_character_, length(x)), 
                  "%Y-%m-%d")
            else stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
        }
    }
    res <- if (missing(format)) 
        charToDate(x)
    else strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT")
    as.Date(res)
}
```

and when the `optional` is specified, it forces by `rep`licating the `NA`, whereas without that it is checking conditions on the first non-NA element and those conditions are all returning `FALSE`, thus it goes into the last `else` which `stop`s

```
xx <- x[1L]
```

and reaches the last `else` condition which `stop` and return with the `error` i.e. if we do this manually

```
> x <- input2
> is.na(x) <- !nzchar(x)
> x
[1] "-"          "2001-02-03" "2002-03-04"
>  xx <- x[1L]
> xx
[1] "-"

> is.na(xx)
[1] FALSE
> !is.na(strptime(xx,  c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"),  tz = "GMT"))
[1] FALSE FALSE
> optional <- FALSE
> stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
Error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: well it still looks inconsistent to me. If `format` argument is required for proper processing, this requirement should be the same regardless of the order of elements. `lubridate` does the job indeed, but my question is about `base::as.Date()`

Comment: @VasilyA updated the post.  It is the way in which the function is constructed with checks

Comment: @VasilyA If you check my update, it is function that is taking the first element for the `if/else if/else` condition that creates the problem

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I see where this behavior comes from, but I still think this behavior is incorrect - or at least it must be documented.

Comment: @VasilyA Every function have some bugs, behavior pattern etc.  I am guessing that this may not be a specific case they may have considered i.e. it checks for blanks (`""`) with `nzchar` or NA with `is.na`, but `-` or `:`, is a rare event

Comment: yes my question was whether we can consider this a bug

Comment: It could be as `input2[1] <- "";
> as.Date(input2)#[1] NA           "2001-02-03" "2002-03-04"` works as expected whereas `> input2[1] <- "a"
> as.Date(input2)
Error in charToDate(x) :..`

Comment: @VasilyA it is actually specified in documentation i.e. `format - character string. If not specified, it will try tryFormats one by one on the first non-NA element, and give an error if none works.`  So, it is a behavior already known